2. Add Two Numbers in LeetCode
сделал такой вот код(вникать в него не нужно),у меня в VS все работает корректно, при переносе его в ЛитКод интерпретатор он выдаёт совсем иные результаты,из-за чего такое может быть?Заранее спасибо за ответ.(Ссылка на задачу : ссылочка)


var addTwoNumbers = function(l1, l2) {
    let big_array = (l1.length == l2.length) ? l1 : (l1.length>l2.length) ? l1 : l2
    let small_array = (l1.length == l2.length) ? l2 : (l1.length>l2.length) ? l2 : l1

    for(let i = 0; i < big_array.length ; i++){
       if(small_array[i] != undefined) big_array[i] += small_array[i]
        if(big_array[i] >= 9 && i == big_array.length-1){
            big_array.push((big_array[i] - (big_array[i] % 10))/10)
            big_array[i] = big_array[i] % 10
            
        }else if(big_array[i] >= 9){
            big_array[i+1] +=  ((big_array[i] - (big_array[i] % 10))/10)
            big_array[i] = big_array[i] % 10
            
        }
    }
    return big_array
};

console.log("First test ",addTwoNumbers([2,4,3],[5,6,4])) 
console.log("Second test ",addTwoNumbers([0],[0])) 
console.log("Third test: ",addTwoNumbers([9,9,9,9,9,9,9],[9,9,9,9]) )


"он все выполняет наперекосяк и тд" - это недостаточное описание проблемы. Будьте конкретнее. Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе (текстом, а не картинкой). Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Я изменил вопрос,надеюсь стало по-понятнее

К сожалению, понятнее не стало.

Один и тот же код по разному проходит тесты у меня на компьютере в VSC и на сайте LeetCode

Я даже не совсем понимаю,как загуглить проблему

Для начала, надо ее конкретизировать и привести к минимальной простой (и скорее всего в процессе сокращений вы и так поймете в чем дело).

Ваша проблема очевидна и она заключается в том что вы используете обычный массив в то время как в описании написано что это связной список или Linked List и вы должны итерировать не по индексу большого массива а по индексу каждого массива по отдельности т.к. они имеют разные индексы для разных элементов.

Диагноз проблемы ваш правильный. Но вот зачем писать про итерацию по индексу, если это связанные списки?

Потому что автор вопроса итерирует два списка по индексу и это неправильно.

А как правильно? Явно не так, как вы написали по индексу каждого массива по отдельности, т.к. никаких массивов и их индексов не существует
